# How to make certain parameters optional in C function

Tags: c, parameters, default-value

I have a situation where in I want one of the parameters of function to be optional. I wanted to know how I can achieve it..?

```
    int mapgw_cm_trace(int trapLog, char *pcMsgId, ...)
```

I want *traplog* parameter to be optional.

Or the otherway of looking at this is that, I set this parameter to a default value(say 1) if this parameter is not sent in the function call...else use the vaLue sent in the function call. Is it possible to achieve this..? I do not want to use *va_args ()*

Comment: `do not want to use va_args` - then why do you have `...` in your function's declaration? Or it just shows, that there are other irrelevant parameters (but fixed number)?

Comment: Don't think there is _default_ value for parameter or something like _optional parameter_ in C.

Comment: How would you call a function that has its **first** parameter optional?

Comment: I'm using ellipsis.. because I'm unaware of the no. of parameters, and its type as well.. I use these parameters just for logging.. and no parsing is done on these..

Comment: @BartFriederichs : It is not about the parameter being first.. I can have the parameter in the middle as well..

Comment: @codinonwheels same question. Optional parameters are always last, as there is no way of telling a parameter is missing if it is in the middle or beginning.

Answer (score 5):

VA lists are bad for many reasons, most notably they have poor type safety. Avoid them.

The usual way to do that in C is to document the function, saying that if `trapLog` has value this or that, then it will not be used. If it should be possible for it have any value, then you can rewrite the function as:

```
int mapgw_cm_trace (const int* trapLog, char *pcMsgId)
```

and document that if `trapLog == NULL` it will not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can u elaborate a little more..  I don't think I understood...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the language features for optional parameters (that won't work here because they expect you to put those parameters last), there is always the possibility to write another function.

```
int mapgw_cm_trace(int trapLog, char *pcMsgId)

int mapgw_cm_trace_with_default_traplog(char *pcMsgId)
{
    // put your default as first parameter
    return mapgw_cm_trace(0, pcMsgId)
}
```

Comment: This is not possible in C, it does not support function overloading. The functions must have different names.

Comment: You are right, I edited it. Been using a C++ compiler for C for too long.